# Font Awesome Icon Master Color

Tags: css, colors, icons

Is there a simple custom CSS for making all icons follow a certain theme color? I have seen the post for editing each icon individually but I am looking for a master one.

Comment: Maybe I should have explained in a little more detail.I am sorry about that!  I am using Frisco Theme from Creative Smitten. http://www.creativesmitten.com/frisco/ I am a rookie Wordpress person. I do have a custom CSS section available. But I also have a php editor. Which one of the answers below would fit in the custom CSS section? I just the standard color to be alter and nothing else with the master file of the icons. The color I would like is #0057b8. Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using CSS it's possible. Either give them all the same class which contains your custom styles or refer all the icons using their common ancestors.

Let's assume you have all icons inside an element of class `element` then you can define all the custom css for icons like:

```
.element i.fa{
/* Your custom styles */
}
```

Change `i.fa` to the concerned element if you have icons on different element other than `i` . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Often templates, like those used for Bootstrap, have separate CSS files for different color themes.

These are merely overrides over the default colors. 
blue.css, green.css, etc.

You could extend Kamlesh's answer by centralizing your color properties in a separate stylesheet that allows for abstraction of the "theme."

**blue.css Example:**

```
i.fa {
   color: #0c9;
}

   .inverse i.fa {
      color: white;
   }
```